# removeobject from nsmutablearray

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, xcode4.5

I m doing a quiz application in which I have stored the correctanswer and its question Id in a NSMutableArray.I m displaying it in a section tableView.Now if I mark another answer in the same section then the prevoius have to be removed and this one has to be attached to the array.
But Im unable to get it .

```
 NSMutableArray *cellSection = [self.finalarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    int n=[cellSection count];
    NSString *questionId=[[cellSection objectAtIndex:n-1]objectForKey:@"QId"];
 for (NSDictionary *dict in selectedOptionandQIdArray) {

        NSString *str=[dict valueForKey:@"QId"];

        [arr1 addObject:str];

    }

    BOOL isTheObjectThere = [arr1 containsObject:questionId];


    if(isTheObjectThere==YES)
    {
         //remove the prevoius answer and replace by the new answer for the same question id 
    }
 [selectedOptionsArray addObject:dictionary1];


    NSDictionary *dictinary2 =[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:questionId, @"QId",  nil];
    [selectedOptionsArray addObject:dictinary2];

    [selectedOptionandQIdArray addObject:selectedOptionsArray];
```

But `isTheObjectThere` is always '`NO`' eventhough there is same question Id.

How can I remove prevoius one and replace by the new one

Comment: what values in arr1, NSLog it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id object = [[array objectAtIndex:0] retain];
[array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[array insertObject:object atIndex:2];
```

Use these lines.

Comment: Here id has no data type so we use this for removing & adding at new index in array...

Comment: But I dont know the index of that Question Id.How can I find it and the compare.?

Comment: First I have to check whether the same questionId exists or not .If exists then replace

Comment: Ok see this link may it helps you in your work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457527/nsmutablearray-replace-object

Answer (score 0):

use `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`. just replace your answer.like this

```
[selectedOptionsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexofrepacingElement withObject:@"newAnswer"];
```